# VBA Excel tricky "Nested" Column Sorting

Tags: algorithm, excel, loops, sorting, vba

I've trying to solve the following problem (believe me, many tries) without success... Please, any suggestion or code is very very welcome!

Problem: I have a bunch of Excel sheets with data organized in a certain way (the data structure in these spreadsheets cannot be changed by other reasons) and I need to export this info in a list to be able to import it in another application.

The spreadsheets are structured like the following sample:

The first column has the elements of the level 0 and, in the other columns, are additional levels. The Levels are matched by the reference in the 1st row (row 1). For example "A" in cell A2 is on the level 0 and the "A10", "A20" and "A30" are level 1, nested in "A". "A1010" and "A1020" are level 2 nested in "A10" and so on.

The number of level, row with info and columns can change widely.

```
    | A |  B  |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |
----+---+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------|
  1 |   |  A  |  A10  | A1010 | A1020 |  A30  | A3010 |
  2 | A | A10 | A1010 | A1011 | A1021 | A3010 | A3011 |
  3 | B | A20 | A1020 | A1012 | A1022 | A3030 | A3012 |
  4 | C | A30 |       | A1013 | A1023 | A3070 | A3013 |
  5 | D |     |       | A1014 | A1025 | A3090 | A3019 |
  6 |   |     |       | A1019 | A1027 |       |       |
  7 |   |     |       |       | A1029 |       |       |
  8 |   |     |       |       |       |       |       |
```

The final list need to be structured this way to be read by other application.
All the corresponding nested levels need to be sequential, like the following.

```
A          <--- Level 0
A10        <--- Level 1 (nested in "A")
A1010      <--- Level 2 (nested in "A10")
A1011      <--- Level 3 (nested in "A1010")
A1012      <--- Level 3 (nested in "A1010")
A1013            ...
A1014
A1019
A1020      <--- Level 2 (nested in "A10")
A1021      <--- Level 3 (nested in "A1020")
A1022            ...
A1023
A1025
A1027
A1029
A20
A30
A3010
A3011
A3012
A3013
A3019
A3030
A3070
A3090
B
C
D
```

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:

- The code will be embedded in these excel files but the files are read only and no data should be written in the file.
- Ultimately, the output will be a TXT file. So, an array containing the final sorted data will be very welcome since we can use that array to perform other tasks that will be needed.
- I need to know the level of every instance.

Comment: **IF** I understand the requirements correctly, the algorithm is quite simple. (Starting with the rightmost column as the "current" column (1) find the value in its first row anywhere in the columns to the left of the "current" column (2) Insert all other rows of the "current" column below the found location (pushing other cells in the found column down) (3) make the next column to the left of the "current" column the new "current" column (4) repeat unless "current" column is A.)  But your question gives no indications of what is not working in your code.

Comment: You're right, I haven't showed my code. But that was just because I couldn't get any reasonable results with it.
Your approach is interesting but I can't figure it out how I can get the level of every instance...

Comment: My approach was using two Do-Loop, one inside the other, like a looping system that goes through a 2D array. However, I was trying to use two array variables to control the index of the row and column being read and connect the size of these array to the corresponding level. Meaning, if a new level was found, the array size will increase by one until every data of that level was obtained. Once that happened, the arrays ware redim to a shorter size (one unit). Inside the index of that level, the value of the arrays is the index of the excel rows and columns already read.

Comment: I don't know if I made myself clear, but I admit this appraoch is far from simple...

Comment: Sorry. I thought the `<--- Level 3 (nested in "A1010")` bits in your question were just comments.  I was thinking you just needed the data sorted into the order implied by the levels and hadn't realised that you actually needed the "level" to be shown as well.

Comment: The algorithm for working out level numbers is still fairly simple (basically just the reverse of my first comment, but setting a number instead of copying cells).  If only you would post your code, it would be reasonably easy to provide you a working version.

Comment: Yes, they are comments. However I need to know the level of every item.

Comment: I give it another shot and I think I figured it out. Please have a look to my answer bellow and give me some feedback if you think the code can be optimized or simplified. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was coding this myself (rather than trying to explain a method for someone else to code this) I would do the following:

```
Type ValueAndLevel
    dataValue As String
    dataLevel As Long
End Type

Dim myData() As ValueAndLevel

Sub Export1()
    ReDim myData(1 To 1)
    'Start the process in column 1, with level being 0
    Process 1, 0
    'Get rid of the last dummy entry added to the array
    ReDim Preserve myData(1 To UBound(myData) - 1)
End Sub

Sub Process(c As Long, l As Long)
    Dim vl As ValueAndLevel
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c1 As Long
    'Start this column at row 2
    r = 2
    Do While Cells(r, c).Value <> ""
        'Store this cell's details
        vl.dataValue = Cells(r, c).Value
        vl.dataLevel = l
        myData(UBound(myData)) = vl
        'Increase size of array ready for next value
        ReDim Preserve myData(1 To UBound(myData) + 1)
        'search for sublevels starting from the column to the right
        c1 = c + 1
        Do While Cells(1, c1).Value <> ""
            If Cells(1, c1).Value = Cells(r, c).Value Then
                'If this column's row 1 matches the value we are looking for,
                'process the column (at a level one deeper than we were at)
                Process c1, l + 1
                'Don't look for any more matching values - assume only one per customer
                Exit Do
            End If
            c1 = c1 + 1
        Loop
        'Get ready to process the next row in this column
        r = r + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

At the end of `Export1` having run, the `myData` array will contain the relevant values and their associated levels.

Comment: I've to admit this code is quite impressive. I'd never get to such solution. The results are exactly what I was hoping to reach. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This code will rearrange the sample you provided in the manner you wish for.

```
Sub Rearrange()
    ' 01 Sep 2017

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ArrIn As Variant
    Dim ArrOut As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim R As Long, C As Long

    C = Columns("K").Column                                 ' output column
    With Worksheets("GML")
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(7, "G"))    ' input range
        ArrIn = Rng.Value
        ReDim ArrOut(1 To Rng.Cells.Count)
        For i = LBound(ArrIn) To UBound(ArrIn)
            For j = LBound(ArrIn, 2) To UBound(ArrIn, 2)
                R = R + 1
                ArrOut(R) = ArrIn(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i

        Set Rng = .Cells(2, C).Resize(UBound(ArrOut))
        Rng.Value = Application.Transpose(ArrOut)

        With .Sort
            With .SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add Key:=Rng, _
                     SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                     Order:=xlAscending, _
                     DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            End With
            .SetRange Rng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Something makes me think the sample data is just sample data and, for instance. "A" might be "Apples", "B" might be "Oranges", "C" might be "Lemons", and "A10" might be "Red apples", "A20" might be "Green apples", etc.  Still, until the OP provides better sample data (or says what is wrong with their own code), this answer is as good as anything at solving the problem.

Comment: @YowE3K :-) Hence the cautious words with which I introduced my idea. But I thought that the sequence of Apples, Oranges and Lemons could be maintained by using the code in a loop, moving the problem to how to define `Rng` and I didn't invest time into this for that precise reason.

Comment: Indeed, this is just a sample data. And the range can vary widely from file to file.
I forgot to mention that, although the code is to be embeded in these excel files, these files are to be read only and the output of this code will be a text file. Meaning, no data should be written in the files.

Comment: @GML A Excel file can be read only and still have information written to it.  After the information is written to some range in Excel, that range can then be written to a text file and the Excel file can be closed without changes being saved.

Comment: I didn't know. However, i'm avoiding to write anything in the files.

Comment: I think you asked a question and got an answer. Select the answer that helped you and move on. If you have another question, ask it in another thread. Don't shift the goal posts. Don't ask another question in this same thread. Besides, your comments on @GML's solution should be under GML's solution and not here.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out.
Can you please validate if this code can be optimized?

```
Sub Export()

Dim rFirstCell As Range
Dim vValue, vValueTemp As Variant
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iLevel As Integer
Dim iRowIndex(), iColIndex() As Integer
Dim sSortArray() As String 'Stores the final sorted items
Dim iLevelArray() As Integer 'Stores the levels of each item

ReDim iRowIndex(0)
ReDim iColIndex(0)
ReDim sSortArray(0)
ReDim iLevelArray(0)

'Define
Set rFirstCell = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(1)
vValue = rFirstCell.Offset(1, 0).Value

If vValue <> Empty Then 'check if there's a value to run the script
    iRowIndex(iLevel) = iRowIndex(iLevel) + 1
    vValue = rFirstCell.Offset(iRowIndex(iLevel), iColIndex(iLevel)).Value
    Do While vValue <> Empty

        'Stores the values
        iLevelArray(UBound(iLevelArray)) = iLevel
        sSortArray(UBound(sSortArray)) = vValue

        'Check if there's a new level using a temp value
        vValueTemp = rFirstCell.Offset(0, iColIndex(iLevel)).Value

        Do While vValueTemp <> Empty
            If vValueTemp = vValue Then
                'New level found
                iLevel = iLevel + 1
                ReDim Preserve iRowIndex(iLevel)
                ReDim Preserve iColIndex(iLevel)
                iColIndex(iLevel) = iCol
                Exit Do
            Else
                iCol = iCol + 1
                vValueTemp = rFirstCell.Offset(0, iCol).Value
            End If
        Loop
        iCol = 0

        iRowIndex(iLevel) = iRowIndex(iLevel) + 1

        vValue = rFirstCell.Offset(iRowIndex(iLevel), iColIndex(iLevel)).Value

        'Check if the value is not empty and
        Do While vValue = Empty
            'The value is empty so, decrease the level
            If iLevel = 0 Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                iLevel = iLevel - 1
                ReDim Preserve iRowIndex(iLevel)
                ReDim Preserve iColIndex(iLevel)
                iRowIndex(iLevel) = iRowIndex(iLevel) + 1
            End If
            vValue = rFirstCell.Offset(iRowIndex(iLevel), iColIndex(iLevel)).Value
        Loop

        If vValue <> Empty Then
            ReDim Preserve iLevelArray(UBound(iLevelArray) + 1)
            ReDim Preserve sSortArray(UBound(sSortArray) + 1)
        End If
    Loop
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW - Your code, when run against the data in the question, just generates the array containing `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"`, and `"D"`.  I assume that means the question's data doesn't match what you actually have in your worksheet.

Comment: My code is working because on my worksheet the cell A1 is not Empty. But, if the cell A1 is empty, you're right, the result is going to be just "A" ... to "D".